# How can I block some special User-agents Via IPTables

Tags: user-agent, firewall, iptables

I need to block packets from any source that includes some special User agents using IPTables. But I don’t want to manage it via `.htaccess` or Apache. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" -j DROP
```

Comment: And what if this text will be part of request body?

Comment: Does not works with encrypted https request. I use ssldump, grep and firewalld in a service.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You could try something using the `string` match with iptables (see `iptables -m string -h`). However, the clients would still be able to connect to your server, the only thing you could do is interrupt the connection in the middle of the request. And if the user agent header happens to be split across multiple IP packets, you are out of luck.