# How to fight against bingbot/2.0

Tags: apache, .htaccess, robots.txt, bingbot

I am tired by bingbot, howto fight against this robot. it create  too session.

I do that in ht access : 
opinion ?

```
#bingbot create too session
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^bingbot/.*         [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://go.away/                      [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bingbot) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

Or use robots.txt

```
User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /
```

Comment: doesn't work.  I delete my session, my stats and 2 mn after I have 32 bingbot

Comment: It might take some time for bots to see your robots.txt

To test the .htaccess, use an user-agent switcher.  Here's a list of user agents for spiders: 

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/

I'll play with this a little bit this evening.

Comment: I tested the htaccess code with the following tool and got a 403 error.

https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/se-bot-simulator.html

It is possible that your logs are still getting hit with this, if that's what you're using to test. Bing will likely stop crawling if it's getting a constant 403.

Comment: If you want to prevent bing from hitting apache at all, use a firewall like IP Tables.  This is an interesting article: http://www.computersolutions.cn/blog/2012/05/msn-bing-crawler-spider-madness/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209551/how-can-i-block-some-special-user-agents-via-iptables <- blocking by user-agent using iptables

Comment: Read this regarding bing bot and robots.txt: http://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2012/05/03/to-crawl-or-not-to-crawl-that-is-bingbots-question/

Comment: I try this :  User-agent: bingbot

Disallow: marketplace/advanced_search.php
Disallow: marketplace/advanced_search_result.php